# Can I use a native application in Java-based heroku app?

Tags: java, heroku

I have a Java application that uses a native program (Graphviz).

Now I want to run this Java application in Heroku. Is it possible to set up the Heroku application so that Graphviz is available to my Java program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this using [multiple buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app) via the [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli):

1. Set your application's default buildpack:

   ```
   heroku buildpacks:set heroku/java
   ```
2. Add the [`apt` buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt) so you can install Ubuntu packages:

   ```
   heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku-community/apt
   ```
3. Look at your configured buildpacks to ensure that the Java buildpack comes last:

   ```
   heroku buildpacks
   ```
4. Add an `Aptfile` to the root of your repository listing the packages you want to install, in this case:

   ```
   graphviz
   ```
5. Commit the `Aptfile` and deploy. The `apt` packages listed in `Aptfile` should get installed first, then your Java application will get built according to the Java buildpack.